# CPU usage problem

Tags: cpu, cpu-load

A few days ago I bought a notebook (Asus N56VZ) and detect a problem with CPU usage. When I am surfing on the Internet or using some programs, CPU usage is jumping from 1-7% to 65-80%.

Can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 5):

The "top" command will easily show you which processes are consuming the CPU.